# Comma seperated values to Dict using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list as follows:

```
lstA = (JOHN_FILE,RGL_MANAGER VICKY_FILE,SALES_MANAGER MAXR_FILE,MANAGER ASHLEY_FILE,TEAM_LEAD TERRESA_FILE,TEAM_MEMBER)
```

I need to convert this into a dict? I tried the following but am getting the error.

```
d1 = dict(item.split(",") for item in lstA.split(" "))

Error: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 7; 2 is required.
```

Objective is, given an employee name, i should get the corresponding job title as value.  Please note that I cannot use pandas for this, and pyspark as well, since i will need to use this in my Lambda.

Thanks

Comment: That `lstA` definition is not valid python. Are there supposed to be quotes in there?

Comment: Quoting this `lstA` and removing parenthesis solves your issue I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is written as a string, your expression works:

```
>>> lstA = "JOHN_FILE,RGL_MANAGER VICKY_FILE,SALES_MANAGER MAXR_FILE,MANAGER ASHLEY_FILE,TEAM_LEAD TERRESA_FILE,TEAM_MEMBER"
>>> dict(item.split(",") for item in lstA.split(" "))
{'ASHLEY_FILE': 'TEAM_LEAD', 'JOHN_FILE': 'RGL_MANAGER', 'TERRESA_FILE': 'TEAM_MEMBER', 'MAXR_FILE': 'MANAGER', 'VICKY_FILE': 'SALES_MANAGER'}
```

Comment: i think its much less readable as this, and spliting it into for loop make it much easier to understand what you are doing

Comment: Thank you all, for the solutions, I have used aerobiomat's suggestion, though it helped me to understand what am doing, with Reznik's code snippet where the single line code has been broken down into steps.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you are searching for this:

```py
lstA = 'JOHN_FILE,RGL_MANAGER VICKY_FILE,SALES_MANAGER MAXR_FILE,MANAGER ASHLEY_FILE,TEAM_LEAD TERRESA_FILE,TEAM_MEMBER'
d1 = {}
for person in lstA.split():
    name, job = person.split(',')
    d1[name] = job
```

explanation:

`lstA` the list of inforamtion you have

`lstA.split()` split the string by space

`person.split(',')` split the person name and its job by `,`

`name, job = person.split(',')` to unpack the values

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a comprehension and the dict function:

```
lstA = 'JOHN_FILE,RGL_MANAGER VICKY_FILE,SALES_MANAGER MAXR_FILE,MANAGER ASHLEY_FILE,TEAM_LEAD TERRESA_FILE,TEAM_MEMBER'

print(dict(p.split(',') for p in lstA.split())
```

Results:

```
{'JOHN_FILE': 'RGL_MANAGER', 'VICKY_FILE': 'SALES_MANAGER', 'MAXR_FILE': 'MANAGER', 'ASHLEY_FILE': 'TEAM_LEAD', 'TERRESA_FILE': 'TEAM_MEMBER'}
```